# Getting CalledFromWrongThreadException when using Handler

Tags: android, android-handler

I'm constantly getting that CalledFromWringThreadException when I press my button.

My program is something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Callback {
    Handler handler = new Handler(this);
    TextView tv = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendRequest);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //...
                        Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(0, new String("\nSending Request from " + sourcePortString));
                        handler.dispatchMessage(msg);
                        //...

                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        tv.append((CharSequence) msg.obj);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I did try removing the `implements Callback` and extending the `Handler` class in an anonymus class, implementing the `handleMessage(Message msg)` method. But I still get the same result when I try to append something to my TextView.

I am missing something.

And I thought I had finally mastered those `Handler`s...

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong method `dispatchMessage`.

Use `sendMessage`.
Regards